What does "This edit would have to be a suggested edit." mean?
I was suggesting an edit for a question, and I got the following error message, which apparently doesn't allow me to submit the suggested edit.

This edit would have to be a suggested edit.

What does that mean? I know I cannot edit every post, since my reputation is still low, but I don't understand what the error message is trying to tell me, or what I am supposed to do.
This is the screenshot of the edit page.







As answered on Meta SO

When you reviewed that post, there was already another suggested edit pending for the same post. You can't suggest an edit while a previous edit is awaiting review, so the system prevented you from doing so.
Yes, that error message could have been less cryptic


Uh! I thought was something happening on beta sites, but I obviously try to edit posts on sites where I am allowed to edit every posts, or on beta sites. :)
